# wp_localize_script, variable is not defined in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I try to load a post with Ajax.

`functions.php`:

```
function my_action_callback() {
        wp_localize_script('jscustom', 'ajax_custom', array(
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
        ));
        wp_enqueue_script('jscustom');
}
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
```

jQuery code in `custom.js`:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    var morebutton = jQuery('#load-more'),
        archive = morebutton.rel,
        deftext = morebutton.text(),
        page = 1;

    morebutton.click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        page++; 

    morebutton.text(ajax_custom.loading);
    jQuery.post(ajax_custom.ajaxurl, {action:'load_more', page:page, archive:archive}, function(data){...
```

When I press the "load more" button, I get an error:

> ReferenceError: ajax_custom is not defined

What is wrong?

Answer (score 11):

[`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) should be called AFTER `wp_enqueue_script`:

> IMPORTANT!: wp_localize_script() MUST be called after the script it's
>   being attached to has been enqueued or registered. It doesn't put the
>   localized script in a queue for later scripts.

Fix it in your function:

```
function my_action_callback() {
wp_enqueue_script('jscustom'); // I assume you registered it somewhere else
wp_localize_script('jscustom', 'ajax_custom', array(
   'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
));

}
```

You can always check in your page's `<head>` if you see your variable.